# How do I store JSON data in html tags?

Tags: javascript, json

I am making a FAQ and want to make it easier editable. Right now it can be only edited in the html file. From a JSON file I want to load all the information in so the json file can be edited if a question or answer needs to be changed or added. I wanted to make some kind of a CRUD but this seems too difficult for me. If it's possible to make a CRUD with this and someone can explain me how or give a tutorial (the data must still be loaded in html elements) that would be awesome.

Nevertheless I'm trying to store the JSON objects in my HTML elements. Inside the `<H2>` goes the category. Inside the `<a></a>` goes the question and inside the `<p></p>` goes the answer. Does anyone know what javascript code I have to use for this? I would like it to check the category and that place all the questions of that category from the JSON file in the correct place. I have tried multiple and tried to looked it up but all in vain. Thanks in advance.

JSON:

```
{
  "question": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Quest",
      "answer": "Ans",
      "category": "Cat"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "Quest2",
      "answer": "Ans2",
      "category": "Cat2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "Quest2",
      "answer": "Ans2",
      "category": "Cat2"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "question": "Quest2",
      "answer": "Ans2",
      "category": "Cat2"
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul id="algemeen" class="cd-faq-group">
    <li class="cd-faq-title"><h2>General</h2></li>
    <li>
    <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0">Question</a>
    <div class="cd-faq-content">
    <p>Answer</p>
    </div> 
    </li>
```

Comment: You need to learn how to write server-side code. You should then learn about databases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would avoid putting any JSON in HTML elements and instead use AJAX to download the data, parse it, and then build the HTML structure using template literals.

```js
function getJSON(callback) {
  const json = '{"question":[{"id":1,"question":"Quest","answer":"Ans","category":"Cat"},{"id":2,"question":"Quest2","answer":"Ans2","category":"Cat"},{"id":3,"question":"Quest3","answer":"Ans3","category":"Dog"},{"id":4,"question":"Quest24","answer":"Ans4","category":"Wolf"}]}';
  callback(json);
}

function sortByCategory(data) {
  return data.reduce((obj, c) => {
    const { category, ...rest } = c;
    obj[category] = obj[category] || [];
    obj[category].push(rest);
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

// Returns the question/answer HTML 
function buildQuestionHTML(arr) {
  
  // Iterate over the category array objects
  return arr.map(el => {

    // In each case return the question/answer HTML
    return `
      <li class="block">
        <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="${el.id}">${el.question}</a>
        <div class="cd-faq-content">
          <p>${el.answer}</p>
        </div> 
      </li>
    `

  // Making sure we join up the final array
  }).join('');
}

// Returns all the HTML from the categorised data
function buildPageHTML(data) {
 
  // Iterate over the categorised data
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, c) => {
    
    // Get the question/answer HTML
    const questionHTML = buildQuestionHTML(data[c]);
    
    // Create the scaffold for the category and
    // add the category name, and question/answer HTML
    const html = `
      <li class="cd-faq-title">
        <h2>${c}</h2>
      </li>
      ${questionHTML}
    `;
    acc.push(html);
    return acc;

  // We're adding the HTML to an array so we need
  // to ensure we join it up into a string
  }, []).join('');
}

function displayQuestions() {
 
  // Get the data
  // This would normally be a call to your server which 
  // would return some JSON data
  getJSON(function (json) {

    // Parse the data
    const questions = JSON.parse(json).question;
    
    // Sort the data by category
    const categoryData = sortByCategory(questions);

    // Get the root element where you want the compiled data to be added
    const root = document.getElementById('algemeen');

    // Build the HTML
    const html = buildPageHTML(categoryData);

    // Add it to the root element
    root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  });
}

// call displayQuestions
displayQuestions();
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.cd-faq-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="algemeen" class="cd-faq-group">
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm trying to read the json from an external file instead of in the text. Do you have an idea how that is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up articles on XMLHTTPRequest, fetch, AJAX. Or search on here for related questions.

Comment: How can I modify this code so that it will create a different <ul> for each category?

Comment: Change the element with id `algemeen` to a div or something, then add a `ul` wrapper to the returned html in the `buildPageHTML` function.